# Convergence theorem for uniformly integrable martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

This is a theorem in my textbook: [image]
Why "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$" and not "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$"?

What's wrong with setting $n=0$, e.g.
$$ X_0 =\mathbf{E}[X_\infty| \mathcal{F}_0] \; ?$$

Comment: The statement holds also for $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Saz, there is nothing wrong with the case $n=0$. All the assertions are true in this case.